# opencv 4.5.3 imshowerror: "error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'"

Tags: python, anaconda, video-capture, opencv, imshow

I'm new to python and openCV and am currently learning how to use openCV with a video tutorial on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXlwWbU8l2o (very popular)

I'm stuck with an error message which I don't know how to solve and would be happy for any help to solve the problem.

This is my program I want to run:

```
   import cv2 as cv
    
    capture = cv.VideoCapture('Video.mp4') 
    
    while True:
        isTrue, frame = capture.read()
        cv.imshow('Video', frame)
    
        if cv.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('d'): 
             break
    
        capture.release()
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I try to run the programm the following error occurs:

```
cv.imshow('Video', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-u4kjpz2z\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: 
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

I use Visual Studio Code and the anaconda python distribution to work on the tutorial. My python version is Python 3.8.8 and I have installed openCV via the anaconda navigator. I have installed follwing openCV packages:

- libopencv 4.0.1
- opencv 4.0.1
- opencv-contrib-python 4.5.3.56
- py-opencv 4.0.1

Moreover I'm working on a windows 10 machine.

I'd appreciate any help!
Best regards

Comment: Oddly similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68911490/error-215-scn-3-scn-4-in-function-cvcvtcolor-while-plotting-in-ma

Comment: [These](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+opencv+cvtcolor+%22-215%22+VideoCapture+is%3Aq) look pretty similar, too.

Comment: You might ask the author of the tutorial you're using to make sure that a valid frame is read before converting it, or did you just leave out that part?

Comment: thanks for the help, I managed to get the code run by commenting out the last two rows and suddenly it works perfectly fine and displays the video. anybody knows why?

Comment: Those two lines should come *after* termination of the loop.